# Are random variables of distributions always independent?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$
Let $(\Omega_1,F_1,Q_1)$, $(\Omega_2,F_2,Q_2)$ be two probability spaces. Let $X\sim Q_1, Y\sim Q_2$ under $(\Omega,F,\mathbb{P})$.

If we now define $\Omega:= \Omega_1\times \Omega_2, F:=F_1\times F_2$ and $\P:= Q_1\otimes Q_2$, then we can define $X,Y$ as the projections onto the first and second coordinate.

Then we have:
$$
\begin{align}
&\P(X\in A , Y\in B ) \\
= {} & \P(\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\}) \\
= {} & \P((A\times \Omega_2)\cap(\Omega_1\times B ))\\
= {} & \P(A\times B)  \\
= {} & Q_1(A)\cdot Q_2(B) \\
= {} & (Q_1(A)\cdot Q_2(\Omega_2)) \cdot (Q_1(\Omega_1)\cdot Q_2(B)) \\
= {} & \P(X\in A)\cdot  \P(Y\in B)
\end{align}
$$

However, this only shows that there's a definition of $\P$ so that $X,Y$ are independent.

How do I show that for all definitions of $\P$ the random variables $X,Y$ are independent?

---

Definition of stochastic independence of random variables as by Georgii:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. $\mathbb{P}$ is defined as a product measure. What other definitions would it have?

Comment: @AlexR. But how can I guarantee that $\mathbb P$ is a product measure if I can not access it in my experiment? Doesn't that mean I have to cover for the eventuality that it is something else, whatever that may be?

Comment: By definition, independence means that if you have a collection $G_i$ of sub-sigma algebras of $\sigma(F)$, then $X_i$ are independent if $P(\cap_i X_i\in A_i) = \prod_i P(X_i\in A_i)$ for any $A_i\in G_i$. Notice that it's with respect to the *same* space. Whereas in your case you have constructed a product space from two individual random variables, and are *defining* $\mathbb{P}$ to be a product measure.

Comment: @AlexR. I think I've found a counter-example thanks to your comment. Can you look over it?

Comment: So to clarify, when the spaces are different, you'll have independence as a consequence of the definition of product measures. If it's the same space, all bets are off.

Comment: See here for example: http://math.iisc.ac.in/~manju/Old/ProbTheory/Notes/1-3%20Independence.pdf

specifically the Definition 2.4 of independence. It assumes the space is the *same*.

Comment: I think I see your source of confusion. When you speak of a collection of spaces $(\Omega_i, F_i, Q_i)$, they are inherently different from each other. As an analogy $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}'$ (where the prime just distinguishes the latter). Even though $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}'$, they are not the same when you speak of functions defined only on the first and only on the second coordinate. If they were the same, then the only points that would exist are of the form $(x,x)$.

Comment: @AlexR. All things together it seems though, that saying "We have independent random variables with these distributions" is only a convoluted way of defining a product measure with projections (though the random variable definition probably spans a few more exotic cases). I've also included the definition I used for independence. When you say "the sapce is the same", don't you mean that for all random variables $X_i$ we have $X_i:(\Omega,F,\mathbb{P}) \to ... $?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, your answer is a counterexample. Here is a way to generate a large family of counterexamples.

Let $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ be finite. Then $Q_1$ is defined by a certain probability mass function $q_1$, so that $Q_1(E)=\sum_{\omega\in E}q_1(\omega)$, and similarly for $q_2$. Furthermore, letting $\def\P{\mathbb P}\P=Q_1\otimes Q_2$, then $\P$ has the mass function $p$, where $p(\omega_1,\omega_2)=q_1(\omega_1)\cdot q_2(\omega_2)$.

Now, choose two particular outcomes $x_1,x_2\in \Omega_1$ and $y_1,y_2\in \Omega_2$ for which $q_1(x_i)>0$ and $q_2(y_i)>0$, for $i\in \{1,2\}$, and choose $\epsilon>0$ which is sufficiently small. Then, define a modified probability measure on $\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$ by the folloiwng probability mass function, which is a slight modification of $p$:
$$
\tilde p(\omega_1,\omega_2)=
\begin{cases}
p(\omega_1,\omega_2)+\epsilon & \omega_1=x_1,\omega_2=y_1\\
p(\omega_1,\omega_2)-\epsilon & \omega_1=x_2,\omega_2=y_1\\
p(\omega_1,\omega_2)-\epsilon & \omega_1=x_1,\omega_2=y_2\\
p(\omega_1,\omega_2)+\epsilon & \omega_1=x_2,\omega_2=y_2\\
p(\omega_1,\omega_2) & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$
You can verify that $\tilde p$ defines a measure on $\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$ whose marginal distributions on $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are equal to $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, respectively. However, $\tilde p$ is no longer the product measure, so the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are no longer independent.

Comment: That's an interesting explicit construction. Do we need the fact that the marginal distribution are equal to $Q_1, Q_2$, or is that a bonus?

Answer (score 0):

Count example:

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}$
Let $(\Omega_1,F_1,Q_1) = (\Omega_2,F_2,Q_2)=(\Omega,F,\mathbb{P})$ and define $X:=X_2:=X_1$.

Then we have for events $A,B$ with  $A\cap B =\emptyset$ and $\P(A) \neq 0 \neq \P(B)$:
$$
\P(X\in A , Y\in B ) = \P(\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\}) = \P(\emptyset) = 0 \neq \P(X\in A)\cdot \P(X\in B)
$$

Therefore, we can construct two random variables that are totally dependent, if they both have the same distribution.

Comment: Indeed, this is a counterexample. There are many counterexamples, even when $\Omega_1\neq \Omega_2$.